# how to pass same data to multiple views in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

From a controller method, I send `$notifications` to the home view and display notifications on a header of my website.

The Profile views extend the home view and I also wanted to display the notifications on the profile view.

But it generates an error that undefined variable $notifications when I request for the profile view.

I think one solution is that to send `$notifications` when returning profile view from controller method, but in the website, there are many views on which I wanted to show notification tab so it's the right way that I am thinking.

I returned the home view by following way

```
return view('home')->with(['unseen_notification_counter'=>$unseen_notification_counter,'notifications'=>$notifications]);
```

here is the code in the home view in the header section

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="notificationlist">
    @foreach($notifications as $notification)
        <li>
            <a href="{{route('user.profile',$notification->id)}}" class="dropdown-item">
                <img src="http://localhost/webproject/public/user_images/{{$notification->image}}" class="img-thumbnil" width="20px" height="20px">
                <strong>{{$notification->username}}</strong>
                <span style="white-space: initial;">sent you a friend request.</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: How are you passing the notifications to the views?

Comment: can you show where are you extending your view?

Comment: Can you show how your getting the notifications as well (sorry) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're wanting to pass the same data to multiple views within your application you could use [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers)

E.g. in the `boot()` method of your AppServiceProvider you would have something like:

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer(['home', 'profile'], function ($view) {

        $notifications = \App\Notification::all(); //Change this to the code you would use to get the notifications

        $view->with('notifications', $notifications);
    });
}
```

Then you would just add the different blade file names (like you would with a route) to the array.

---

Alternatively, you could [share](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) the notifications with all views:

```
public function boot()
{
    $notifications = \App\Notification::all(); //Change this to the code you would use to get the notifications

    view()->share('notifications', $notifications);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a `BaseController`, and share data from there like so:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use View;

//You can create a BaseController:

class BaseController extends Controller {

    public $dataVariable = "some data";

    public function __construct() {

       $anotherVariable = "more data";

       $notifications = Notification::where('is_seen',0)->get(); // assuming this gets unseen notifications
       $unseen_notification_counter = count($notifications); 

       View::share ( 'notifications', $notifications );
       View::share ( 'unseen_notification_counter', $unseen_notification_counter );
       View::share ( 'data_variable', $this->dataVariable );
       View::share ( 'another_variable', $this->anotherVariable );
    }  

}
```

All controllers that extend `BaseController` will have access to the data. Do something like this:

```
class DashboardController extends BaseController {

    public function Index(){
      return view('index'); // all the shared data is available in the view ($notifications and $unseen_notification_counter)
    }
}
```

Hope it works.